# Singularities of $\frac{z^5}{1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I find and classify the singularities of $f(z)=\frac{z^5}{1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4}$? Do I need to use the Laurent series of $f(z)$? If so, how do I determine the Laurent series of $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: No, there is no need to compute the Laurent series. Just notice that you are confronting the Cyclotomic polynomial, as
$$(1+z+\cdots + z^n)(1-z)=1-z^{n+1},$$
whose roots are easy to compute. After that you just get a series of simple poles.